# Generalization of R objects that are either a data.frame or a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a few questions related to the writing of a function that can work both on matrices and data.frames. Imagine for example:

```
DoubleThatThing <- function(thing) {
   stopifnot(is.matrix(thing) | is.data.frame(thing))
   2 * thing
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a general term for an object that is either a matrix or a data.frame? Something to replace `Thing` in `DoubleThatThing`.
2. Is there a generally accepted or widely used variable name for `thing`?
3. Is `is.matrix(thing) | is.data.frame(thing)` the best way to test for such objects?

Comment: Thanks in advance. I feel the question is borderline, I would have preferred to ask on the R chat but my proxy at work won't allow me. I'll understand if it gets closed.

Comment: I think matrices and data frames are quite different for R. A matix is a special form of array, which is itself a vector with additional attributes for its dimensions. On the other hand, a data frame is a list of variables of the same lengths. So I'm not sure there will be a term for "the thing" you're looking for...

Comment: I think I would prefer seperate methods for data.frames and matrices. The test for object class is pretty much included then.

Comment: "R chat"? What on earth is that? I hope you don't mean R-help.

Comment: Could you cut the matrix/data.frame row/column wise and operate with a list?

Comment: @Dwin, I think flodel means this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: Oh, good. Didn't want flodel to get flamed in R help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would help you or if this gives what you want. But why not declare a `generic method` and define methods for `matrix` and `data.frame`?? Here's a dummy/silly example:

```
# generic method
my_fun <- function(x, ...) {
    UseMethod("my_fun", x)
}

# default action
my_fun.default <- function(x, ...) {
    cx <- class(x)
    stop(paste("No method defined for class", cx))
}

# method for object of class data.frame
my_fun.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
    print("in data.frame")
    tapply(x[,1], x[,2], sum)
}

# method for object of class matrix
my_fun.matrix <- function(x, ...) {
    print("in matrix")
    my_fun(as.data.frame(x))
}

# dummy example
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c(1,1,1,2,2))
mm <- as.matrix(df)

> my_fun(df)
# [1] "in data.frame"
# 1 2 
# 6 9 

> my_fun(mm)
# [1] "in matrix"
# [1] "in data.frame"
# 1 2 
# 6 9 

> my_fun(as.list(df))
# Error in my_fun.default(as.list(df)) : No method defined for class list
```

Answer (score 4):

Matrix and data.frame are really quite different underneath. The thing they have in common is that they have two dimensions. So you can test for that common attribute:

```
DoubleThatThing <- function(thing) {
   stopifnot(length(dim(thing)) == 2)
   2 * thing
}
```

But I'm not sure why this will be preferable to `is.matrix(thing) | is.data.frame(thing)`.

Comment: And, to add a bit to finish off the other part of the OP's question: `thing` can simply describe what it is, as in `twoDimThing`.